# How do users rate Facebook Connect site?

Tags: facebook

The fairly new addition of the Facebook app center raises a question for me. I have a facebook connect site. App Center allows websites to be listed there as well as canvas apps. I see sites like Pinterest are there and they have ratings (1-5 stars). The app center listing process even requires that you have a certain rating and enough positive feedback before they will list your app publicly. I do not see any API or social plugin to allow my site visitors to rate the site. How do these other sites have a rating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to rate an app at the moment, instead Facebook randomly ask users to rate apps they've used based on a variety of criteria.

The primary reason for this is to make it harder to manipulate the ratings so users can have confidence that the score they see is accurate.

Comment: So at some point on Facebook, it has asked people to rate the external website Pinterest.com that they have visited in the past?  Interesting, I've never seen that happen.

Comment: Ok I finally saw it. On the right when you go into a Facebook application of any kind, it will sometimes ask you to rate recently used applications.